# Can I override the LVM volume group name using storage: layout in the autoinstaller?

Tags: server, system-installation, lvm, cloud-init

I have physical machines with multiple (n) hard-drives that I want to install identical copies of Ubuntu 20.04 on using the [Automated Server Install](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference). My hope was to just be able to use the LVM layout on each disk, to keep things as simple as possible.

My autoinstaller config uses the following,

```
storage:
  layout:
    name: lvm
    match:
      path: <DISK NAME E.G. /dev/sda>
```

The first install works just fine - but of course install number two barfs in Curtain/Subiquity because the LVM volume group already exists (`ubuntu-vg`),

```
/dev/ubuntu-vg: already exists in filesystem
```

Is it is possible to override the volume group name using the layout method? Checking the installer logs, it looks like `ubuntu-vg` is hardcoded into some default `subiquity.conf` template somewhere, and may not be accessible at all. Is there some other way to override that in another argument that I'm not seeing? Or am I stuck with using action-based config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

Though it was a simple task to just pull the layout being applied from the generated subiquity configuration. I ended up just using that as a template template to generate the appropriate action-based config to the appropriate disk. Here's the basic yaml with an included boot and grub partitions - with slight modifications to use the entire disk for the OS.

```
storage:
    config:
      - id: disk-sda
        type: disk
        ptable: gpt
        path: /dev/sda
        wipe: superblock
        preserve: false
        name: main_disk
        grub_device: true
      - id: partition-0
        type: partition
        device: disk-sda
        size: 1M
        flag: bios_grub
        number: 1
        preserve: false
      - device: disk-sda
        size: 1G
        wipe: superblock
        flag: ''
        number: 2
        preserve: false
        type: partition
        id: partition-1
      - fstype: ext4
        volume: partition-1
        preserve: false
        type: format
        id: format-0
      - device: disk-sda
        size: -1
        wipe: superblock
        flag: ''
        number: 3
        preserve: false
        type: partition
        id: partition-2
      - name: <CUSTOM VG NAME HERE>
        devices: [partition-2]
        preserve: false
        type: lvm_volgroup
        id: lvm_volgroup-0
      - name: <CUSTOM LV NAME HERE>
        volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
        size: -1
        preserve: false
        type: lvm_partition
        id: lvm_partition-0
      - fstype: ext4
        volume: lvm_partition-0
        preserve: false
        type: format
        id: format-1
      - device: format-1
        path: /
        type: mount
        id: mount-1
      - device: format-0
        path: /boot
        type: mount
        id: mount-0
    version: 1
```